# Strophe: Anonymous User

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I am using Strophe js and ejabbered server for chat using XMPP prtotocol.
Here I am allowing anonymous user to chat. But when an anonymous user is providing a name for chat, I am not getting the name of the user instaed a large encoded number I am getting. How can I fix this.

Please Help..

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Sounds like you're grabbing the SID, what's the "large encoded number" look like?

Comment: yes Mark that is SID. but instead of SID i want to display nick name. How can I do this.